# Android programmatically update application when a new version is available in api 24 and api 25

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to update my App in Nougat but I couldnt, I am getting the below error

## code

```
File o = new File(String.valueOf(uri));
Uri myURI= FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", o);
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
promptInstall.setDataAndType(myURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

## error

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{9dfaa8c
1646:com.google.android.packageinstaller/u0a17} (pid=1646, uid=10017) that is
not exported from uid 10173
```

Please Help me to Fix this issue

Comment: That should be OK. You might try removing `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i Found the Solution

```
long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
if(downloadReference == referenceId) {
Timber.d("Downloading of the new app version complete");
//start the installation of the latest version
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installIntent.setDataAndType(dm.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadReference),
                                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(installIntent);
```